# How do I set environment variable in Setting.json[Meteor]

Tags: meteor

export CLUSTER_WORKERS_COUNT=auto(All Available Core)

Need to add this setting.json

Comment: This does not go to `settings.json`, but to a startup/deployment script directly to the command line. If you do not wish to use the environment variables, Cluster also has JS API.

Comment: I have added this in main.js


     Meteor.startup(() => {
          process.env.CLUSTER_WORKERS_COUNT='auto';
    
      });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using meteor on windows command line .

export CLUSTER_WORKERS_COUNT=auto

so for windows you should use this

set CLUSTER_WORKERS_COUNT=auto

this should resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I have added this code in main.js

```
 Meteor.startup(() => {
       process.env.CLUSTER_WORKERS_COUNT='auto';

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not set up in settings.json it's a shell variable 
https://meteorhacks.com/introducing-multi-core-support-for-meteor/